# What's the point of DuplicateHandle's DUPLICATE_CLOSE_HANDLE flag?

Tags: winapi, pipe

I'm trying to track down an issue in some Win32 pipe code I inherited. This is the [old standby](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/08/10184375.aspx) of `CreatePipe()` x2 followed by `DuplicateHandle()` x2 and `CreateProcess()`.

```
    if (!CreatePipe(&child_stdout_read, &parent_write, &security, 0) ||
      !DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), parent_write,
      GetCurrentProcess(), &child_stdout_write, 0, TRUE,
      DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)) {
        throw std::system_error(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
    }
```

What has me confused is the flag `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE` being used in the `DuplicateHandle()` calls. According to the Microsoft docs this means that the source handle will be closed after duplication.

What exactly could be the point of making a copy of a handle (to a pipe) into the same process, and then closing the original? Why not just use the original?

Comment: It's duplicating the pipe's write handle into the child process.  I assume the parent has no need to keep the write handle around so it lets DuplicateHandle() close it.

Comment: But if you look, in this case the "from" process and "to" process are the same. I'll go clarify that.

Comment: Well, that's odd.  Maybe the code does something weird with the parent_write and child_stdout_write handles.  I can't really hazard a guess based on the miniscule snippet given.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic here, but the DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE flag is one of the only ways to close a handle in a remote process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks to me that the key is in the `TRUE` parameter. That is the `BOOL bInheritHandle`, so what this code does is to duplicate the handle to make it inheritable.

Normally, this could be easily done by setting the `security.bInheritHandle` to `TRUE` when creating the handle. But in this case that would make *both* handles inheritable. And clearly, the original author only wants to inherit the `child_stdout_write`.

Note that the same effect can be achieved with the less contrieved code:

```
SetHandleInformation(handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
```

Comment: Ahh. I bet this is it. At least, I think that's probably what he was *trying* to do. He *did* set `security.bInheritHandle=true;`. However, there's some later code (that he had commented out, probably because he wasn't using the right handles) where he turns off the `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` bit on a couple of handles. So probably what he *wanted* to do was make only the two handles for the client inheritable, but he ended up writing a whole lot of extra code (and getting his handles mixed up in the process).

Comment: Yes, redirecting std{in,out} is a mess. 2 pipes times 2 handles per pipe times 2 processes, equals 8 handles to think about at the same time!

Comment: ...with that code commented out, also it was making a couple of extra handles inherited, which was the source of the bug that got me looking at this in the first place. Yay! Accepting this, since it answers both my question and my meta-question :-). Now to clean this code up...